# NSManagedObjectModel initWithContentsOfURL returns nil occasionally

Tags: ios, core-data

I am using Core Data and have a situation in a live app where I am getting some crash reports with the following error:

```
Cannot create an NSPersistentStoreCoordinator with a nil model
```

I have found that this occasionally happens in the simulator (as well as the device) **but it does not consistently** happen on either, and I have not yet found a correlation of what causes it to happen sometimes and not other times.

After doing some debugging, I have found that the root cause (from the code's perspective) is that occasionally the managedObjectModel creation method returns nil. Here's my implementation from AppDelegate:

```
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel {
    if (__managedObjectModel != nil) {
        return __managedObjectModel;
    }
    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"AppName" withExtension:@"momd"];
    __managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
    return __managedObjectModel;
}
```

Every now and then I'm lucky enough to have the debugger running when the crash happens, and I've confirmed that the above method is being called, and the `initWithContentsOfURL:` method is executed, but returns `nil`.

Can anyone think of why `[[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL]` might occasionally return `nil`?

Comment: See this answer:
1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221225/nsurl-initfileurlwithpath-nil-string-parameter-on-nsmanagedobjectmodel?rq=1

Comment: Thanks, malcolm! So far, we haven't had any crashes with the beta testers after making that change. I'll let it sit a couple more days to make sure, but looks like that may have done it!